# How to automatically dropping data and recreate one table in JPA of Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'd like to do test in my local env, but want to always drop data and recreate one table (only one table, not all tables) in JPA of spring boot, how can I achieve that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use liquibase for manage this approach. in liquibase confiquration file you can check if exists table in database schema drop table and recreate the target table. Note if there are other tables, you should not take any action.
https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/springboot/springboot.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following properties in your `spring-boot` app.

```
spring:
  sql.init.mode: always   
  datasource:
    url: ...
    username: ... 
    password: ...
  jpa:
    defer-datasource-initialization: true 
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Then you can place under `src/main/resources` a file named `data.sql` which could contain `DELETE FROM MY_TABLE` which will clean the table completely.

With the property `defer-datasource-initialization: true`  you ensure that the script will be executed only after hibernate has finished processing your schema and doing changes in DB during app initialization.